# Constraint on a procedure so it can only be executed once every 7 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, procedure

I have the following SQL code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [pr_Prize]
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @User_ID INT = (
    SELECT TOP 1
        u.[User_ID]
    FROM
        [User] u
    RIGHT JOIN [Issue] i ON u.[user_ID]=i.[Reporter_ID]
    WHERE   
        i.[Date_submitted] BETWEEN GETDATE()-7 AND GETDATE()-1
    AND u.[HRD_Staff]='0'
    ORDER BY NEWID()
    );
INSERT [Prize] ([User_ID])
SELECT [User_ID]
FROM [User]
WHERE [User_ID]=@User_ID
GO
```

Which seems to work the way I want it to

My question is:
How do I modify this code so it can only be executed once every 7 days

Prize table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Prize] 
(
   [prize_id] [int] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
 , [Prize_Date] [date] DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL
 , [User_ID] [int] NOT NULL
 , CONSTRAINT [PK_Prize] PRIMARY KEY ([Prize_ID])
 , CONSTRAINT [FK_User] FOREIGN KEY ([User_ID]) REFERENCES [User] ([User_ID])
)
```

Comment: The SP executes code inside its body. You call a SP when you want. If you want to schedule your SP execution you can use Sql Server job

Comment: Stick a timestamp on the prize table and check it’s at least 7 days ago or something, but your requirements aren’t completely clear (should it error, be on a schedule, ...). The idea is to try something yourself and ask on here when you’re stuck, not come here looking for solutions.

Comment: In table `prize` add a datetime column to store when is Prize given. At the beginning of procedure find last time and skip the rest of the code if 7 days have not passed

Comment: Basically you only want to make changes where the current date is at least 6 days after the last update?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **JOB** using SQL Server Agent and set time for execute the procedure(In your case 7 days)

Steps is as follows

```
1. Right Click on jobs => New Job
2. Write  Job Name  My_Job  and job description.
3. Click On Step Button
4. Click on  New Button
5. Write Step name and choose database name and write store procedure in 
   command text box. after click to ok button.
6. Click on Schedules button, Click to new button Create New Schedules
7. Write Schedule name and set execution timing (7 days) when you want to execute Job 
   Scheduler.
   and click to ok button.
8. Click on your job name which you have created.
   Right click on your job name which you have created. and click on Start 
   job  at step
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to *enforce* that prizes are only awarded exactly every 7 days, then you would enforce that as a *constraint* against a *table*. Something like:

```
create table Prize (
    User_ID int not null,
    PrizeAwarded date not null,
    PreviousPrize as CASE WHEN PrizeAwarded = CONVERT(date,'20150101',103) THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(date,DATEADD(day,-7,PrizeAwarded)) END persisted,
    constraint PK_Prize PRIMARY KEY (PrizeAwarded),
    constraint UQ_Prize_Previous UNIQUE (PreviousPrize),
    constraint FK_Prize_Chain FOREIGN KEY (PreviousPrize) references Prize(PrizeAwarded)
)
```

Here, I'm assuming that the first prize is to be awarded on 1st January 2015. All other prizes are (uniquely) linked to the previous prize by a foreign key constraint and are thus enforced to be 7 days apart.

In the alternative that prizes can be awarded *more* than 7 days apart then you would allow `PreviousPrize` to be supplied rather than calculated and then use a `CHECK` constraint to ensure that `PrizeAwarded` and `PreviousPrize` are at least 7 days apart.

Either way though, if you want enforcement to ensure quality data, it's done at the table level.

Comment: this is what my current table looks like:
`CREATE TABLE [Prize]`
`[prize_id] [int] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,`
`[Prize_Date] [date] DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL,`
`[User_ID] [int] NOT NULL`
`CONSTRAINT [PK_Prize] PRIMARY KEY ([Prize_ID])`
`CONSTRAINT [FK_User] FOREIGN KEY ([User_ID])`
`REFERENCES [User] ([User_ID])`

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have column where you store Prize date, just use it to check if 7 days has passed since last prize awarded and prevent further code from happening.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [pr_Prize]
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @lastPrizeAwarded DATETIME;
SELECT @lastPrizeAwarded = MAX([Prize_Date]) FROM [Prize];

IF (@lastPrizeAwarded IS NULL OR DATEADD(DAY,7,@lastPrizeAwarded) < GETDATE())
BEGIN

  DECLARE @User_ID INT = (
    SELECT TOP 1
      u.[User_ID]
    FROM
        [User] u
    RIGHT JOIN [Issue] i ON u.[user_ID]=i.[Reporter_ID]
    WHERE   
        i.[Date_submitted] BETWEEN GETDATE()-7 AND GETDATE()-1
    AND u.[HRD_Staff]='0'
    ORDER BY NEWID()
  );
  INSERT [Prize] ([User_ID])
  SELECT [User_ID]
  FROM [User]
  WHERE [User_ID]=@User_ID

END
ELSE
BEGIN 
  // What you want to do if 7 days have not passed
  // Maybe send message, throw exception or do nothing
END
```